# How to access element in returned object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been given a socket which returns me an object.

And i'd like to access one of its values, however I don't know how to.
What i need is a "balance" value for every object.

Down below there is a screenshot from my console.
Thanks for the help in advance

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to access properties of standard JS objects?

Comment: your question is not clear enough, I think you could have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Excuse me if it's not clear enough - i will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On both cases you need to access the properties by `[]` notation.

**1)** You can do it in `for in` loop

```js
var obj = /**/; //Your object

for(key in obj.message){
  
  if(obj.message.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          obj.message[key].balance <- use this syntax to get the balance of each item
    }
}
```

**2)** Or via [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var obj = {
  message:{
    item1:{
       balance: 1000
    },
    item2:{
      balance: 2000
    }
  }  
};

Object.keys(obj.message).forEach(key => console.log(obj.message[key].balance));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ObjectName.message.forEach(item,index){
  console.log(item.message);
}
```

You can either iterate over the `hashs` only and get the `message` value.
Use object name instead of `ObjectName` on code.

Answer (score 0):

well, let say you now keep your object in a variable called `my_obj`, then do following:

```
if (my_obj.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
  for(key in my_obj.message){
    if ((typeof my_obj.message[key] == 'object') && (my_obj.message[key].hasOwnProperty('balance'))) {
      var balance = my_obj.message[key].balance;
      // Now do something what you need
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to you, I've menaged to pull it off.
Down below there is a working code :)

```
    var objcts = $.each(msg.message, function () {});

    for (key in objcts) {
        if (objcts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var balance =  objcts[key].balance;
            console.log(balance);
        }
    }
```